# Clip composable with vector drawable

Tags: android, vector, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to clip my composable with custom shape i would store in drawable.
At the moment i'm getting the pathData from a vector and apply it to a composable in this manner:

```
Outline.Generic(
                   // Transform pathData to path and then transform it into compose usable path 
            path = PathParser.createPathFromPathData(
                // Parse the pathData from SVG 
                VectorDrawableParser.parsedVectorDrawable(
                    context.resources,
                    drawableRes
                ).pathData
            ).asComposePath()
        )
```

The problem is that at the moment it doesn't scale the pathData so it can adapt every composable size and not just apply the size defined in SVG.
Do you have any idea on how i can make it scale?

Don't hesitate to ask for more code if you want to try things